# How to store field value from firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

For example, in the image below, I would like to store the value "hi" in a string in Flutter from Firestore. However, when I print the value, I keep getting `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'`

Any idea how to do this?

Edit: One thing I am trying to do is basically get the data and see if its equal to a specific value. For example, if the field `text` is equal to "hello", then I would print "hi" to the screen
[image]

Code:

```
final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<String> getString(docID) async {
  String? roleValue = '';
  DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await firestoreInstance
      .collection('messages')
      .doc(docID)
      .get();

  roleValue = docSnapshot.data()!['text'];
  return roleValue;
}
```

Comment: Can you include your code snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I added the code. It is quite wrong though I beleive

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not awaiting the call as this is an async function.
You have to add `await` just before calling the `getString` function.

```dart
final result = await getString('abc);
print(result);
```

Now the result will no more `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'`